# Unable to Cast a variable MYSQL

Tags: mysql, casting

I'm using the CAST() function in order to cast a variable that is already set during a session.The code below explains it.

```
SET @X="'b'1000001''"

SET @Y=CAST(b'1000001 AS UNSIGNED);
```

*(THIS PERFECTLY WORKS GIVING ME THE VALUE 65)*

```
SELECT @X;
(THIS GIVES ME THE VALUE OF X AS b'1000001')

 SET @Y=CAST(@X AS UNSIGNED);
 (THIS DOESNOT WORK!!)
 (GIVES ME VALUE AS 0 FOR Y)
```

Can anyone explain to me as why the variable is not being able to convert the variable @X in the cast() function.Is there any work around if I want to cast a variable in mysql?

Comment: THIS DOESNOT WORK!! --> what's the error message you're getting?

Answer (score 0):

```
mysql> SELECT CAST("'b'1000001''" AS UNSIGNED), CAST(b'1000001' AS UNSIGNED);
+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
| CAST("'b'1000001''" AS UNSIGNED) | CAST(b'1000001' AS UNSIGNED) |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
|                                0 |                           65 |
+----------------------------------+------------------------------+
```

You can CAST *numeric* values to UNSIGNED; casting strings will give you zero, unless there are leading digits.

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are starting with.  You mentioned `SET @X="'b'1000001''"`, but I suspect that is not really where you are starting.

Comment: i just have a variable .i need to use it in cast can i do it?

Comment: How was the variable constructed?  Why was it not constructed with `65` or `100001`?

Comment: Its not about using 65 but what if i have big binary number and later on i need it to cast it how am i supposed to do it?

Comment: Strip off the extra quotes and try to start from there.

Comment: can u please elaborate coz removing strings from the binary number wont work causing removing quotes around the binary looses its meaning